# How to install paintstore for django

Tags: python, django, color-picker

How do you install paintstore for django? Paintstore is gotten from http://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-paintstore. I installed it using command

```
python setup.py install
```

installation went fine, I think, at least no error, but when I do

```
python manage.py sql appname
```

it says

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "manage.py", line 10, in <module> execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 443, in execute_from_command_line utility.execute()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 382, in execute self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 196, in run_from_argv self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 231, in execute self.validate()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 266, in validate num_errors = get_validation_errors(s, app)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/validation.py", line 30, in get_validation_errors for (app_name, error) in get_app_errors().items():
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/loading.py", line 158, in get_app_errors self._populate()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/loading.py", line 64, in _populate self.load_app(app_name, True)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/loading.py", line 88, in load_app models = import_module('.models', app_name)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 35, in import_module __import__(name)
File "/ProjectDir/ProjectName/app/models.py", line 7, in <module>
class Bag(models.Model):
File "/ProjectDir/ProjectName/app/models.py", line 10, in Bag Color = models.ColorPickerField()
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'ColorPickerField'
```

I tried copying the content of paintstore folder inside django-paintstore-0.1.2 (you get this one when extracting the django-paintstore-0.1.2.tar.gz file) but still to no avail. The README is of no help if any for it only say

```
Install the app with your preferred Python packaging utility
```

I've added paintstore to INSTALLED_APPS too and I didn't forget to import it using

```
from paintstore.fields import ColorPickerField
```

Thanks in advance for helping. Btw I don't mind if you suggest something else for the ColorPickerField as long as it is as good or better as this one, but please do tell me how to install it to work correctly.

Comment: Can you show the line where you create the field?

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit different than using django models. It is not models.ColorPickerField. It should be just ColorPickerField.